# how to show wizard using css spirit from single image

Tags: css

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have the above image now by using css how to show the image as below.

[image]

I'm totally new to this. I have tried this:

```
.step{
    background-image: url(images/myimage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 40px -40px;
}
```

From the above I can see the grey image how to over lay the orange image on the grey?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with a single class and a single element like in your question, not with *that* image (because the circles have borders, because of the numbers inside, etc).

What you actually *can* do is using [`CSS3 multiple background images`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds) capabilities (take a look at [a nice article about it](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)), in your case to place two times the *same* image in two different places, one over the other;

this is how close you can go: http://jsfiddle.net/APNZL/

As you can see, there're several drawbacks: the numbers should be added in another way, the middle circle is cutting the gray line, and the last circle needs to be limited by the div width to cover the next gray line...

---

But you can do it with two different divs, one with the empty background image, the other with the "full" one, placed one over the other using absolute position, limiting the width of the first image, and using z-index...

> **Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/APNZL/1/

Code (you would use only one container and change the class to the first div, this is only a *test-case* to show you all the possibilities):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nosteps"></div><div></div>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="onestep"></div><div></div>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="twosteps"></div><div></div>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="threesteps"></div><div></div>    
</div>


.container{        
    margin: 20px;
    width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;    
}
.container div{    
    width: 230px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKtl.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.container div + div{
    z-index: 1;
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}

div.nosteps {
    width: 0px;    
}
div.onestep {
    width: 70px;    
}
div.twosteps {
    width: 140px;    
}
div.threesteps {
    width: 230px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably aiming to make those clickable links.

First thing you want is to create an html structer that is suitable to your design. In your case this :

```
<div class="spirit">
    <div class="button1"></div>
    <div class="button2"></div>
    <div class="button3"></div>
</div>
```

then you can style each button by using the following

```
.spirit .button1 {display:inline-block;background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKtl.png'); width:70px; height:40px; background-position:0px 0px;overflow:hidden;}
```

when somebody click on the link or when the mouse over the link.. you need to do something like this :

```
.spirit .button1:hover, .spirit .button1:active {display:inline-block;background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKtl.png'); width:70px; height:40px; background-position:0px 0px;overflow:hidden;}
```

you can control the image position by using the  background-position

more information can be found on here : [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: i am not aiming for clickable links.